# Callback url for Android intent

Tags: java, android, url

I'm working with a payment solution with another company, and in their API i have to send my callback url for when the transaction is complete. Are there any way to find the url to my application? My application is opening the payment application with an url, and after it's dont it should redirect to my application.

Any ideas on how i can solve this?

Some sample code bellow on how i open the payment application:

```
Intent vippsIntent = openVipps(getContext(), finalURL);
                    startActivity(vippsIntent);


public static Intent openVipps(Context context, String url){
    try{
        context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("no.dnb.vipps");
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

    }catch (Exception e){
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking